# Trouble running GWT-Maven project in Eclipse -- Unable to find 'com/myco/clearing/product/ProductPlus.gwt.xml' on your classpath

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Win XP, Maven 3.0.3 and GWT 2.4.  I created a GWT-Maven project and imported it into Eclipse following the instructions here -- http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html.  After I added an additional source folder (target/generated-sources/gwt, a step not mentioned in the instructions), I right-clicked on my project, selected "Run As" -> "Web Application" and got this error ...

```
Loading modules
   com.myco.clearing.product.ProductPlus
       [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/myco/clearing/product/ProductPlus.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

Do you have any ideas how I can configure Eclipse to solve this problem?  I haven't done anything else other than the steps I mention.

The .gwt.xml file is created by the archetype and is located in the src/main/resources/war directory.  Its contents are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='ProductPlus'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />

  <!-- We need the JUnit module in the main module,               -->
  <!-- otherwise eclipse complains (Google plugin bug?)           -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.junit.JUnit' />

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='war.client.ProductPlus' />

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client' /> 
  <source path='shared' />

</module>
```

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 4):

Try using m2Eclipse to run your app... because your app is Mavenized, you will probably run into trouble trying to run it with the GWT Eclipse Plugin.
What I do is:

- Right-click on your project folder
- Select "Run As > Maven build...
- This will let you create a new run configuration. If you only want to
  run the app, just add **gwt:run** to your goals. If you want to build
  then run, add something like **clean install gwt:run** to your goals.

Maybe this will also help:
  - Make sure that in **Project > Properties > Google > Web Toolkit**, you have the "Use Google Web Toolkit" checkbox selected (this should add the generated folder to your class path automatically".
  - Check that Eclipse knows this is a Maven project. If it is, you should have a folder called "Maven Dependencies". If it's not, right-click on your project, select **Configure > Convert to Maven Project**

Comment: I did everything you suggested, including, create a run configuration with "clean install gwt:run".  However, running that configuration results in the same error, '[ERROR] [ProductPlus] - Unable to find 'ProductPlus.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?"  I am baffled by this because this file is auto-generated and located in my src/main/resources/war directory.  I am going to edit my response to include the file's contents.

Comment: Your module file, in a Maven-GWT project, should be located in src/main/resources/com/yourcompany/, which should "mirror" your sources which should be located in src/main/java/com/yourcompany/. You shouldn't have a war folder in a Maven-GWT project! Compiled code goes to the 'target' folder. Have a look at the Layout of folders in the link you posted yourself (Maven GWT Plugin). When you specify the Entry-point class, the path should be relative to src/main/java/, so you specify it as <entry-point class='com.yourcompany.client.EntryPoint' /> for example.